# Android Intllij 14 Export Signed Android Package

Tags: android

i'm using GoogleMap in application and after create new sign key into intllij and match that with Google API key i must be attach and export apk file with created sign file. but i dont have any menu item in `Menu->Tools->Android->Export Signed Android Package` where this option in intllij 14. i'm trying to find it but i can not fount it and found any document about this version of Intllij

Answer (score 0):

It is in another place:

> Build > Generate Signed APK...